# "Arimasu" or "imasu" when mentioning both living and inanimate objects

Tags: grammar

For example, if I were to describe a room that contains a book and a dog, would I say

部屋に犬と本があります　or 部屋に犬と本がいます　？

Or would I perhaps have to find a new way to word this sentence entirely?
I know this is super basic level stuff, but it's weirdly difficult to find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

います is used for living objects and あります is for inaminate ones, so you have to say 部屋に犬がいます、そして、本があります。

Comment: I see, so the categories should be separated this way, but I imagine one could still use と within the categories? eg. 部屋に犬と猫がいます、そして、本とテレビがあります

Comment: 部屋に犬と猫がいます、そして、本とテレビがあります is correct. If plural objects belong to the same category, we say like what you showed.